# New column does not appear

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework, model

I added a column to the table (dahili_sube_id).

[image: picture1]

I updated model from database but the new column does not appear in intellisense:

[image: picture2]

Comment: Please provide the code too.

Comment: You seem to be using a "free-floating" `.mdf` file in your Visual Studio solution - are you **sure** that the changes you made were actually applied to that `.mdf` file of yours?? Did you make the change on the server, and forgot to update your separate `.mdf` file by any chance?

Comment: i updated database and model.edmx but new column still does not appear in intellisense :(